# Modify placeholder style for Word 2007 citations.

Tags: ms-word, bibliography

I read that defined styles are located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Bibliography\Style

I use ISO 690 and when I insert citation field placeholder for a reference in document, it uses the following format (source_number).

But I need to change that to [source_number], replace () parantheses with [].

Could someone experienced point out which part of the code should I change to adjust this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the one at http://bibword.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14646

But if you want to do it yourself, you have to look in the XSLT, for the places where

- /b:Citation/b:FirstAuthor
- /b:Citation/b:LastAuthor

are used. The first one indicates that this is the first citation in a series while the second one indicates that this is the last one.

Yves